# RxJS combineLatest with startsWith in Angular gives error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to trigger an action after change on one of the streams:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

const from$: Observable<number> = this.form.controls['input1'].valueChanges;
const to$: Observable<number> = this.form.controls['input2'].valueChanges;

Observable
  .combineLatest(
    from$.startsWith(0),
    to$.startsWith(0), 
    (a, b) => {
       console.log(a, b);
  });
```

The thing is that I am getting an error:
`error TS2339: Property 'startsWith' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.`

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/startwith.html) method in question is not plural...

```
from$.startWith(0),
```

Rather than

```
from$.startsWith(0),
```

Comment: Happy days! I'm glad to help.